# How do I create a session for each anonymous user in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence

I'm writing a chatbot interface using Flask for users to query the Google Palm2 LLM via Vertex AI. Once complete I'll package this up in a container and publish it using Cloud Run. I'm using the ChatModel class from the Google aiplatform python sdk, the (very sparse!) documentation is here:

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/vertexai.language_models.ChatModel

The chat_model.start_chat() call returns a ChatSession that maintains state and context of the chat session, so the LLM can answer questions with context. The code snippet in question looks like this:

```
chat_model = ChatModel.from_pretrained("chat-bison@001")
parameters = {
    "temperature": 0.2,
    "max_output_tokens": 256,
    "top_p": 0.8,
    "top_k": 40
}
chat = chat_model.start_chat(
    context="""Context about the bot goes here""",
)
```

The challenge is, once I give access to our users and have multiple people hitting Cloud Run at the same time, they are all going to be inside the same ChatSession, which will lead to crazy race conditions and is not an option.

So I'm wondering, is there a way to use Flask sessions, and tie each incoming anonymous user to their own copy of chat_model.start_chat()?